# Average two numbers if the second number exists

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have two columns (Google Sheets) of numbers similar to:

```
10.453   12.178  
12.654   0
```

The third column is:

- if number higher than `0` exists in both columns, display an average of the two
- else just display the one figure entered (in either column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing it, is by using the `AVERAGEIF` formula.

### Formula

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:B1, ">0")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I had no idea this function existed. By far the least complicated out of the two

Comment: That is brilliant!  
pre-race it shows a div/0 error if both are 0 but that's ok :)  This one also works across google sheets/excel/open office.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to do this`if a1>0 and b1>0 then average a1 and b1 else add a1 and b1`

```
=if(AND(A1>0,B1>0),AVERAGE(A1,B1),add(A1,B1))
```

Obviously you'll have to plug in your own cells for a1 and b1
You can find all the google functions documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, that's half-way there...  if one column has no entry then it'd just display the one number that is entered? at the moment it shows nothing if one column is blank

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread the question. Included in the edit on the main post add(a1,b1) will return as '0' when both are blank and when one cell is full it will return the cell and when both it will execute the average

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much - have a great day!